Can't select a class of a div element and add another class to this element
I am working on this GPS project and I ran into a problem. I wanted to build a grid of 360x180 grid-items each and each grid-item represents one single GPS coordinate, which dynamically gets a own very specific class so that I can identify the coordinate later and work with it. Unfortunately the browser returns me this Error message: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList').
I tried to select the exact individual class of the coordinate and then used the classList.add() method to add a new class ('active'), which I wanted to manipulate in the CSS so that this coordinate will get a red background & it would be visible on the grid. Didn't work well, also I was playing around with the Selector but nothing worked for me. The only thing that strangely worked is to manually set the colour in the css like this:
.column-350-row-100 {
  background-color: rgb(207, 18, 11);
}

but that obviously isn't very helpful.
html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>GPS-coordinate Tool</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid-container"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

javascript:
'use strict';

//creates grid (for visual understanding) for every single GPS-coordinate. Then add's for each div a specified class.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const container = document.querySelector('.grid-container');
  for (let lo = 1; lo <= 180; lo++) {
    for (let la = 1; la <= 360; la++) {
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      div.className = 'grid-item';
      container.appendChild(div);
      div.classList.add(`la-${la}-lo-${lo}`);
    }
  }
});

// "Generates" and returns random GPS coordinates in an object 
const randomGpsCoordinates = function () {
  const gpsCoordinate = {
    latitude: Math.trunc(Math.random() * 360) + 1,
    longitude: Math.trunc(Math.random() * 180) + 1,
  };
  return gpsCoordinate;
};

//empty array to save all Objects which consist of one GPS coordinate pair each (longitude, latitude)
const gpsCoordinates = [];

//Generates and fills the array with each GPS coordinate
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  gpsCoordinates.push(randomGpsCoordinates());
}

//Problem to solve: this doesn't work, in the Browser it shows me that the '.la-5-lo-100' should exists, but if I try to select it it ends in an error
// => TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
document.querySelector('.la-5-lo-100').classList.add('active');

css:
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(360, 1fr); /* Creates 18 columns */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(180, 5px); /* Creates 36 rows of 50px each */
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 14px; /* Optional for text inside grid items */
}

.active {
  background-color: rgb(207, 18, 11);
}

.column-350-row-100 {
  background-color: rgb(207, 18, 11);
}


This throws error because your adding elements with Javascript and at that moment the DOM elements it is looking for does not exist,
This is what you have and it is not working:
document.querySelector('.la-5-lo-100').classList.add('active');

please check if the element actually exists:
const element = document.querySelector('.la-5-lo-100');
    if (element) {
      element?.classList?.add('active')
    }

and if this didn't work, please move the classlist adding line below the second for loop at the top of your Javascript file.
and if this didn't work, after the first foor loop add a let variable so it signals you that the items are fully loaded and then try to add the className,
it goes like this:
let hasFinishedRendering = false;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      const container = document.querySelector('.grid-container');
      for (let lo = 1; lo <= 180; lo++) {
        for (let la = 1; la <= 360; la++) {
          const div = document.createElement('div');
          div.className = 'grid-item';
          container.appendChild(div);
          div.classList.add(`la-${la}-lo-${lo}`);
        }
      }
     hasFinishedRendering = true
    });

const element = document.querySelector('.la-5-lo-100');
if (element && hasFinishedRendering) {
  element?.classList?.add('active')
}


You have a viable answer so let's have a bit of fun.

Generate a visual grid with the 180 X 360 size
Toggle ONE noted in the question with classes (see code comments)
Use a JavaScript class called Rectangle to contain our functionality
Generate 5 random coordinates and toggle those with a class
Use a click handler to toggle classes for color
Use that same click handler and detect a shift key to toggle a class for size and color
Use a constructor in our class to set the instance values and to call a setup method that uses those
Add some event handlers (click) in the constructor

Try clicking various places and shift clicking to toggle.


/* expression class with name for our stuff */
const Rectangle = class Coordinates {
  name = "Something Good";
  containerSel = ".grid-container";
  constructor(height, width, containerSel) {
    this.latitudeCount = height;
    this.longitudeCount = width;
    this.containerSel = containerSel;
    this.container = document.querySelector(this.containerSel);
    this.gpsCoordinates = [];
    // call method now to set things up
    this.startup();
    //setup is done now so now that the element exists we can select it by class.
    //Problem to solve: this doesn't work, in the Browser it shows me that the '.la-5-lo-100' should exists, but if I try to select it it ends in an error
    let lo100 = document.querySelector('.la-5-lo-100');
    lo100.classList.add('active', 'active-100');
    lo100.textContent = "X";
    console.log(lo100);
  }

  // Getter
  get coord() {
    return this.randomGpsCoordinates();
  }
  // method
  startup() {
    this.container.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      this.handeClickMethod(e);
    });
    //creates grid
    this.createGrid();
    //Generates 5 array and fills each with a random GPS coordinate
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      this.gpsCoordinates.push(this.randomGpsCoordinates());
    }
    this.markRandomPlaces(this.container, this.gpsCoordinates);
  }

  handeClickMethod(e) {
    //console.log('click:',e.currentTarget);// grid container
    // console.log('click:',e.target);//grid div
    //console.log('click:', e.type);
    switch (e.type) {
      case "click":
        console.log('clicked:', e.target);
        console.log('clicked:', e.shiftKey);
        if (e.target.classList.contains('grid-item')) {
          e.target.classList.toggle('clicked');
          if (e.shiftKey) {
            e.target.classList.toggle('bigger');
          }
        }
        break;
      case "ArrowDown":
        // some code here…
        break;
    }
  }

  // Method
  createGrid() {
    //creates grid
    for (let lo = 0; lo <= this.longitudeCount; lo++) {
      for (let la = 0; la <= this.latitudeCount; la++) {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        this.container.appendChild(div);
        div.classList.add(`la-${la}-lo-${lo}`, "grid-item");
      }
    }
  }
  // Method
  randomGpsCoordinates() {
    // "Generates" and returns random GPS coordinates in an object 
    const gpsCoordinate = {
      latitude: Math.trunc(Math.random() * this.latitudeCount) + 1,
      longitude: Math.trunc(Math.random() * this.longitudeCount) + 1,
    };
    return gpsCoordinate;
  }

  markRandomPlaces(container, coords) {
    coords.forEach((coord) => {
      const gridItem = `.la-${coord.latitude}-lo-${coord.longitude}`;
      console.log(gridItem);
      container.querySelector(gridItem).classList.add('active');
    });
  };
};

/* setup and create an instance of our class */
const containerSel = ".grid-container";
const latCount = 360;
const longCount = 180;
const grid = new Rectangle(latCount, longCount, containerSel);
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.grid-container {
  border: solid 1px #00ff00;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(180, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(360, 1fr);
  /* 4px size */
  font-size: 0.25em;
}

.grid-item {
  border: solid 1px #ff0000;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

.active {
  background-color: #0000ff;
}

.active.active-100 {
  border-color: #00ff00;
  background-color: #00ff00;
}

.clicked {
  border-color: #0000ff;
  background-color: #0000ff44;
}

.bigger {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: #ffff00;
}
<div class="grid-container"></div>



